# React/Typescript spread operator bug when using a compareTo method inside a custom componen

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I faced I bug I don't totally understand so I would like to know why it happens. I understand it has something to do with the {...} spread operator but unclear what is the root of the problem.

Here is a simplified class of the one I used:

```
class Item {
    id:number;
    constructor(id:number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    compareTo = (i2:Item) => {
        return this.id === i2.id;
    }
}
```

Now this "Item" class was inside another custom class so I copied it with spread operator but when I started to use the object I faced a weird bug when comparing the item to itself:

```
const selectedObj = { item: new Item(1) };
let item:Item = {...selectedObj.item};
console.log(item.id) // 1
console.log(item.compareTo(item)) //true
item.id = 123;
console.log(item.id) //123
console.log(item.compareTo(item)) //false
```

When I inspected this further I noticed that inside the compareTo method "this.id" did not change. Why does this happen?

Comment: I've edited your code to make it a [mre]; please let me know if I have somehow misinterpreted your intent

Answer (score 2):

You've initialized the `compareTo` [field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions); as such, it does not have its own [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context.  Instead `this` refers to whatever it refers to outside the arrow function body; for a field initializer it's the class instance under construction.  Which means that `compareTo` is always going to bound to the specific class instance it was constructed with, and *not* the object on which it was called.

If you modify `compareTo` to log whether `this === i2`:

```
compareTo = (i2: Item) => {
    console.log(this === i2)
    return this.id === i2.id;
}
```

you'll see this behavior:

```
let item: Item = { ...selectedObj.item };
item.compareTo(item); // logs false
item.compareTo(selectedObj.item); // logs true
```

which demonstrates that `item.compareTo` is not bound to `item`, but is always bound to `selectedObj.item`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAECSAuBTAttA3gKGt6BLAJgFzQB2ArsgEaIBOA3FjsAPYkTw1nDzM0AUBYuSq0AlOkY4c8ABa4IAOgLQAvHnwMpAX0nQWyAA5gaiACrNV0AQCZiCFOJUA+CVKks2zEIgUhmAcz5ZeVUVNVxrUV0pE3gyGhJoYMVlMPDrJQ1dHR0MD3ZoCERvbkR8AHlKACtLNDwkZCFEAHc4Br4AFgBWADZxXO94epQ7BtroBUmikqQK6qUxrQYMXAaFfSMTcwEG0TpoAHoD6D9-GAAzMBAilbWN4zNmPmnEUrmqhYd9o5OAmA4yIgMEA)